A way to clear the screen in C? Methods like clrscr() through conio and system("cls") is not working. Is this also a thing specific with Clion?
*Additional required info, I'm on windows, I use CLion & I'm still kinda new.
*
So I was recently trying to use the clrscr() from conio.h & also system("cls") from stdlib.h it seems like it's not working.
Clrscr() not being able to use.
I also tried using system("cls") but it also doesn't seem to work and rather than screen clear being performed, it is just echoing my input.
Input being echoed when I use system("cls")
Here, the system("cls") is used after the register and login display right over here on this code:
Code for system("cls")
This is also the same place where I tried using clrscr() so yea I would love some help on this.
I looked at some other posts & also tried to gpt it and most of the measures that I tried wasn't working so I'm curious if it's a CLion specific feature as well?

It depends on your OS/environment. Assuming Windows Terminal or any modern *nix terminal, printf( "\033[2J" ); fflush( stdout ); should do it...

possible duplicate of or helpful How do you clear the console screen in C?

@Dúthomhas that just printed the "←[2JUsername:" this instead of clearing the screen.

Clion specific How can I clear console while running program in CLION

Does this answer your question? How do you clear the console screen in C?

For future reference, please do not post images of errors, a text in the question would suffice. Also, as an FYI - clrscr is actually an implemention defined in the legacy / defunct DOS C compiler such as Microsoft C / Borland C. The function can easily be trivialised to use the ANSI escape codes or use ncurses.

Maybe you can enable Emulate terminal in the output console inside Run | Edit Configurations in CLion. I've tried it in my Mac and it works fine when clearing the built-in terminal. But there're also some limitations about this feature JetBrains CLion Doc.
